# Qual o melhor método de compressão de uma imagem de 2500 ppi?

Tags: compressão-de-imagem, compressão

De preferencia sem perdas de qualidade. Algo parecido com o WSQ (porém, este é somente para imagens de até 500 ppi).

Comment: O ideal é você fornecer suas referências sobre o assunto (links, documentação, ferramentas que usa, etc). Na verdade, o que sua pergunta tem a ver com programação?

Comment: Preciso saber qual o melhor método para implementar em uma aplicação desenvolvida para Android, no qual ela captura a imagem através da própria câmera e comprime usando algum método(esse q eu estou procurando).

Answer (score 2):

Não há diferença de algoritmos que dependam da resolução da imagem.  A resolução é apenas um parâmetro que mapeia o número de pixels na imagem para unidades de medida físicas -  tipicamente se fala em "300 dpi" (querendo dizer 300 ppi *pixels per inch* e não *dots-per-inch*) em "imagens para impressão".

2500 PPI é uma senhora resolução - possivelmente usada em filmes coloridos de slides. Mesmo os mais loucos displays LCD ficam abaixo ou em torno de 500 PPI de resolução.

Então, se você tem uma imagem para aparecer em 2 x 1 polegadas a 2500 PPI ela ainda será uma imagem de 5000x2500px  -e é esse número de pixels que você tem que comprimir. A resolução ser 2500 PPI, ou 1 pixel por metro (caso em que essa mesma imagem se extendria por 5Km de paisagem), não difere em nada o tratamento algoritmico sobre os pixels. A resolução é um único campo de poucos bytes no arquivo final, que serve como "dica" do tamanho final para alguns dos programas de visualização/impressão.

Vi agora que esse padrão WSQ foi desenvolvido para tratar de armazenamento de imagens de impressão digital  - daí temos uma idéia do seu domínio e tipos de imagens que você precisa armazenar.  Pode ser que o WSQ seja ótimo para armazenar os detalhes de uma impressão digital que apareçam na escala de 500PPI - e perca em outros - mas isso tem a ver com o tipo de imagem e tipo de detalhes específicos do seu domínio de trabalho.  Se o WSQ não for bom em outras resoluções, e você quiser algo sem perdas, use arquivos PNG mesmo - que é o suficientemente bom para imagens genéricas - se ficarem grandes demais para sua aplicação, um formato como o [WebpP do Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/) pode funcionar melhor.